# MPDF is not working in codeigniter (PHP version 7.2)

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, autoload, mpdf, php-7.2

I installed mpdf on my server, but When i am running my code then it showing the error

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: Error

Message: Class 'Mpdf\Mpdf' not found

Filename: 
/home/jewelmarts/public_html/royal.chains/application/controllers/admin_panel/Collection.php

Line Number: 374

Backtrace:

File: /home/jewelmarts/public_html/royal.chains/index.php
Line: 317
Function: require_once
```

here is my code

```
 public function download_pdf($id){
    require(MPDF);
    $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['tempDir' => MPDF_TEMP_PATH]);
    $html = '<span>test</span>';
    print_r($html);die;
    $mpdf->AddPage();
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
    $mpdf->Output($file,'I');
}
```

Here is my constant which is , I am using in my code

```
define('MPDF',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/vendor/autoload.php');
define('MPDF_TEMP_PATH',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/tmp');
```

also please check my command of installing mpdf

[image]

Please help me to resolve the issue

Thank you in advance